# pip package available but not listed?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have a package that I had once pip-installed myself from local files and which is available from Python with `import mypackage`. It is however nowhere to be seen in `pip list` or `conda list`. Where else could it be and what could possibly have happened? This lack of visibility makes it all the more frustrating in that I need to delete/update the package, but I can't.

Comment: Since this package is local, `pip` has no idea it exists because it isn't published to PyPi

Comment: @coderman1234 That can't be. It used to be listed by `pip list`. The problem is that it isn't anymore for some obscure reason. Publishing to PyPi has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Usual suspects in my case are:
pip2 / pip3 - are you using the same version now that you used when you installed that package?
Are you / were you in a virtual environment?
I know these sound trivial, just wanted to check - sometimes the simplest solution is the answer.

Comment: @kkubina I never used `pip3` nor have I set up any virtual environment.

Comment: maybe your `PYTHONPATH` changed? are/were you able to locate the files belonging to that module? if you are on linux you could use `locate`

Comment: or i think you can get the location of the modules with `pip list -v`

Comment: @kkubina Well that the very problem: `pip list | grep -i mypackage`  returns nothing. And yet, `import mypackage` runs just fine in Python. I didn't touch `PYTHONPATH` at all, or else other things would have broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be embarrassingly obvious, but I'll write it here for the benefit of others who may run into the same "problem".

I actually had deleted the pip package, which explains why it wasn't listed. However, I loaded it in Python from a directory whose subdirectory was `mypackage`. Had I moved to another directory, things would have been obvious, but the directory structure "tricked me" into thinking the package was still installed by `pip`.